# Producing a Glowing Star with the Transparent Package and Pdflatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-pic, transparent, tikz-fadings

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\textheight 8.5in \textwidth 5.75in 
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{transparent}


\definecolor{darkpurple}{RGB}{48, 25, 52}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings, calc}
\tikzfading[name=dim fade, inner color=transparent!40, outer color=transparent!100]
\tikzfading[name=bright fade, right color=transparent!100, left color=transparent!100, middle color=transparent!0]
\tikzfading[name=long bright fade, right color=transparent!100, left color=transparent!0]

\newcommand{\glowstar}[3][.5]{\fill[white,path fading=dim fade](#2)circle[radius=#1*.6];
    \foreach \t in {0,60,120}{
    \fill[rotate around={\t:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(.9*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(0,.05*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.9*#1,0)$)--($(#2)+(0,.02*#1)$)--cycle;
    \fill[rotate around={\t:(#2)}, white,path fading=long bright fade]($(#2)-(.5*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(0,.04*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.5*#1,0)$)--($(#2)+(0,.04*#1)$)--cycle;
    }
    \foreach \l [count=\n from 0] in {#3}{
        \fill[rotate around={\n*90:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(\l*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(.4,.06*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.4,.06*#1)$)--cycle;
     }        
    \fill[white] (#2)circle[radius=#1*.13];
    }

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[darkpurple] rectangle (8,6);
\glowstar[1.8]{4,3}{1,1,1,1}% length of left,bottom,right,top
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces what I want:

[image]

However, I want to use this for a document which requires the `transparent` package and compiles with `pdflatex`.

But, when I run the above code with `\usepackage{transparent}`, the following is produced:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I produce the first output while invoking the `transparent` package and compiling with `pdflatex`?

Thank you.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. I get the first picture independent of wether the `\usepackage{transparent}` is commented or not. What version of LaTeX are you using? When did you last update your packages?

Comment: I have purchased a recent version from TUG; however, I have run into problems with installing it. Though it seems to have installed properly, there are still recent packages that should be there and I cannot access them. For some reason, the computer always seems to revert to the older edition of Tex Live. I wish I could figure out what I am doing wrong. But thank you for your answer---it works fine on my end.

Comment: I can not help. I am using MacTeX. There should be plenty information on google and this site on how to install and update TeX Live. Are you sure you have purchased a version of LaTeX(and not some malware) - I did not know it was possible. Maybe you mean, that you donated?

Comment: @hpekristiansen  I am sure. I contacted TUG directly and spoke to someone in Oregon, U.S. When the package arrived it was from TUG. If I may, let me ask you this---when you update MacTex, do you have to delete your old version, or are you able to install over the old one? And if so, how does your computer know which version to access? Many thanks.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Maybe it was a donation, but I was quoted and charged a cost of either $10 or $20 (U.S.)

Comment: Ok - that makes sense, I guess that you can buy a physical disc. Are you using satellite internet in Oregon? On the computer I have now there is only installed one LaTeX version, but I remember that there could be multiple installed(maybe an option to keep the old one in the install process) and then you can choose which one to use in the system settings. You do not need to delete the old one. Keep it for safety until the new one is working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138876/discussion-between-hpekristiansen-and-mlchristians).

Comment: @hpekristiansen Many thanks for sharing this information and the invitation to continue  in chat---but (I'm not in Oregon, TUG seems to be based there)---and it's kind of late where I am. Hopefully, and motivated by your comments, I will try again in the morning to figure out why I am not able to access the new version of Tex Live. Thanks again for all your help---and for the earlier patch---it is indeed a most helpful answer for many reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are using an old version of `transparent`. You can see in the manual history section that the pgf(TikZ) compatibility was added in 2018:

> [2018/11/18 v1.3] • Added code for pgf compatibility, see
> https://github.com/ho-tex/transparent/issues/1

The link gives this patch by u-fischer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{transparent}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs\endcsname\relax
\else
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    % \pgf@sys@addpdfresource@extgs@plain{%
    \pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs{%
      \TRP@list
    }%
  }%
  \let\TRP@addresource\relax
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hello \texttransparent{.3}{World}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[opacity=.5] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\makeatletter
\end{document}
```

I have no way of testing this, and it should also not be needed. -upgrade and update your LaTeX installtion.

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer; it is most helpful.